# Ruby on Rails, deleting files from paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

i've been using Paperclip, when deleting is done, it is just deleting the attachments, but the images saved in the file system is not being deleted.can anybody plz tell how to delete the images from the file system using paperclip itself.

the code i've been using is

```
has_attached_file :image_o_filename,
    :styles => {
      :tn => ["100x100#",:jpg ,:name => :tn],
      :w => ["640x480>",:jpg, :name => :w],
      :l_tn => ["200x150#",:jpg, :name => :l_tn]
    },
    :path => "/places/hotels/:image_pre_path/images/:basename_:style.:extension"
```

when i delete the photos from the view, images are getting deleted from the database but not from the file system with the above path, images remain without getting deleted. what might be the reason ??

and no errors generated in console also..

Comment: Please share your code - paperclip in it's default config handles file deletion of of the box.

Comment: Is your console displaying any errors about paperclip?, i think it may be permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip has a very nice built in delete method, I was stuck on a very similar problem and was very well informed in this solution:
I created a method inside the controller called delete_image then from the view I could call this method.

```
def delete_image
  @user.image.destroy
end
```

I had the image attached to a user instance and this worked perfect, don't forget to define your method in the routes file in your config/routes.

Good luck also you can look up more information here:

See: Rails Paperclip how to delete attachment?